# The maximum for $xy \sin \alpha + yz \sin \beta +zx \sin \gamma$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, maxima-minima, geometric-inequalities

Question:

Deduce the maximum of $xy \sin \alpha + yz \sin \beta +zx \sin \gamma$ if $x,y,z$ are real numbers that satisfy $x^2+3y^2+4z^2=6$ with $0<\alpha,\beta,\gamma<\pi$ such that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=2\pi$.

Currently, I am not very sure how to approach the problem. I had an idea to consider the area of a triangle made of 3 smaller triangles with areas $\frac{1}{2}xy \sin \alpha$, $\frac{1}{2}yz \sin \beta$ and $\frac{1}{2}zx \sin \gamma$ respectively. However, that kinda got me no where as I did not have any good ideas on how to use the condition $x^2+3y^2+4z^2=6$. Moreover, that would have assumed $x,y,z\geq0$ which might not be the case.

So, is there a way to deduce the maximum without a calculus approach?

Comment: Just a thought.  We may imagine $x$, $y$ and $z$ emanating from one point; as all angles are less the $\pi$ their endpoints form a triangle. Now the area of that triangle is to be maximized.

Comment: Yes that was my inital idea. But, then i am stuck on how to maximize the bigger triangle given the condition $x^2+3y^2+4z^2=6$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea. I was asked to solve it from someone. We are not sure about the original source. But, it most likely Olympiad/Math competition based.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I finally arrived at an answer. First, lets reduce the cases we need to look at. Clearly $\sin \alpha, \sin \beta, \sin \gamma >0$. So, if one/two of the variables $x,y$ or $z$ is negative, the expression $xy \sin \alpha +yz \sin \beta + zx \sin \gamma$ will not be maximum. Clearly, if all three $x,y,z$ are negative, it is the same when they are positive for the expression $xy \sin \alpha +yz \sin \beta + zx \sin \gamma$. This means we can reduce to the problem to only when $x,y,z>0$.

Consider the following triangle;
[image]

Let $CD=x, BD=y, AD=z$ with $\angle CDB=\alpha,\angle BDA=\beta$ and $\angle ADC=\gamma$. This implies that the area of $ABC$, I'll denote it as $[ABC]$, will be $\frac{1}{2}(xy \sin \alpha +yz \sin \beta + zx \sin \gamma)$.

Let $DE,CF$ be altitudes with respect to $AB$, where $E,F$ are on $AB$. Let $AE=m, BE=n, DE=h$ with $CF=H$. This implies that $z^2=m^2+h^2$ and $y^2=n^2+h^2$.

Okay now we are gonna bash this with inequalities,
$$\begin{align} 
6 &=x^2+3y^2+4z^2\\ 
&=x^2+3h^2+3n^2+4h^2+4m^2\\
&=x^2+7h^2+3n^2+4m^2\\
& \geq \frac{(x+h)^2}{1+\frac{1}{7}}+\frac{(n+m)^2}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}}\tag{1}\label{eq1} \\
& \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{(x+h)^2(n+m)^2}{\frac{8}{7}\times\frac{7}{12}}} \tag{2}\label{eq2} \\
& =2\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}(x+h)(m+n)\\
&\geq \sqrt{6} (H)(m+n)\tag{3}\label{eq3} \\
&=2\sqrt{6} [ABC].
\end{align}$$

Now $\eqref{eq1}$ is due to Cauchy Schwarz Inequality, $\eqref{eq2}$ is due to AM-GM Inequality and $\eqref{eq3}$ is due to Triangle Inequality. I guess equality does occur for each case.

So this implies that;
$$\begin{align}
& 6\geq 2\sqrt{6} [ABC]\\
\Longleftrightarrow & \sqrt{6} \geq 2[ABC]=xy \sin \alpha +yz \sin \beta + zx \sin \gamma.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the maximum of $xy \sin \alpha +yz \sin \beta + zx \sin \gamma=\sqrt{6}$.